# Auto-GPT Command evaluate_code returned: Error: The model: `gpt-4` does not exist

Tags: python

I'm working with [auto-gpt](https://github.com/Significant-Gravitas/Auto-GPT) and I got this error:

```
Command evaluate_code returned: Error: The model: `gpt-4` does not exist
```

and it's like it can't go furthermore.

what should I do?

Comment: Have you set up your paid account?

Comment: I only have openai API key.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to delete it, since it has a positively-scored answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Update your .env file in your repo so that both are = to gpt-3.5-turbo

```
SMART_LLM_MODEL=gpt-3.5-turbo

FAST_LLM_MODEL=gpt-3.5-turbo
```

this issue is happening because you do not have API access to GPT4.

Comment: I have access and a paid api account and I still have this error on gpt-4

Comment: or probably when you run out of usage limit.

Comment: To get API access for GPT-4 you (currently) need to join the waitlist. See https://help.openai.com/en/articles/7102672-how-can-i-access-gpt-4